# How do I use a filter action in Symfony?

Tags: php, symfony1, filter, action, symfony-1.4

How can I use filter action from page that not contain filter form (e.g. by submit or GET request)?

When I pass parameters in the following URL

```
<module_name>/filter/action?module_filters[_csrf_token]=62a17afab45d56382974f9a495abee7c&module_filters[id]=3998
```

I get an error in filter form:

```
csrf token: CSRF attack detected.
```

or

```
<module_name>/filter/action?module_filters[id]=3998

csrf token Required
```

When I execute

```
$filters -> disableCSRFProtection()
```

in my template, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to do this your template with:

```
$form->disableCSRFProtection();
```

Or you can disable CSRF in your form class with this:

```
$this->disableLocalCSRFProtection();
```

Or you can render it as part of your form in your template with this:

```
$form['_csrf_token']->render();
```

Hope that helps.